# How to match the multiple selected options in the form to the database by query?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, html-select

I have created a Shop Search Form for my web site, where users can select multiple district.
I want to ask after I receive the multiple selected options for district, how to return the searching result for users' selected options?

e.g. Users can select US and JP, then my result return SHOP in US or JP

**search.php**

```
<select name="district" id="district">
<option value='US'>US</option>
<option value='UK'>UK</option>
<option value='JP'>JP</option> ... </select>
```

**result.php**
I know to get multiple selected is by using:

```
foreach ($_GET['district'] as $selectedDistrict)
    $district[] = $selectedDistrict;
```

but how to write the matching query?

such as `SELECT * FROM shop WHERE district = '$district'`?

Answer (score 2):

Use IN.

```
$in='"'.implode('","',$_GET['district']).'"';
$where_part="WHERE district IN($in)"
```

It will end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE district IN('JP','UK')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yet, I can't use $_GET['district'] inside implode to get the result, instead, I use the below suggestion and combine with yours
$district = '"'.implode('","',$districtArray).'"';
and now, I success!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `<select name="district" id="district">` with `<select name="district[]" multiple="multiple" id="district">` and then try this

```
<?php
$districtArray=$_POST['district'];

   $sqlDistrictArray=join(',',$districtArray);  

   $findShopQuery="SELECT * FROM shops WHERE district IN ($sqlDistrictArray)";
  ?>
```

Comment: Your suggestion is great! yet, the problem is the query must be a string e.g. IN ('UK', 'JP'), but yours is (UK,JP), so can't get the result accurately. Therefore, I combine your answer and the above answer, and get my result correctly!

thanks you two!!

Comment: Sure, since you found the answer helpful then you might as well upvote it.